# Как послать Referer через WebView в API до 8-й версии?

Tags: android, webview

Мне нужно послать запрос `Referer` через `WebView`. Есть метод 'loadUrl(String url, Map<String, String> additionalHttpHeaders)', но он для 8 Api у меня 7-ой. Как реализовать отправку запроса на сервер?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для версий API ниже 2.2 можно попробовать вытащить часть кода из 2.2, пройдясь по исходникам, начиная с функции loadUrl

```
public void loadUrl(String url, Map<String, String> extraHeaders) {
    switchOutDrawHistory();
    WebViewCore.GetUrlData arg = new WebViewCore.GetUrlData();
    arg.mUrl = url;
    arg.mExtraHeaders = extraHeaders;
    mWebViewCore.sendMessage(EventHub.LOAD_URL, arg);
    clearTextEntry(false);
}
```

И переопределить WebView на свой пользовательский класс, насколько это возможно.

P.S. Но лучше просто перейти на 2.2.

Comment: Спасибо)Уже перешёл)